# How to get the elements in OWLClassExpression

Tags: owl-api

May I ask if I'd like to extract `OWLClass element` in an `ObjectUnionOf OWLClassExpression`, such as `ObjectUnionOf(<OWLClass> <OWLClass>)`, What kind of method in **owl-api** should I use to obtain these two **OWLClasses**?

Answer (score 0):

The method is OWLObjectVisitor:

```
OWLObjectVisitorAdapter visitorAdapter = new OWLObjectVisitorAdapter() {
 @Override
 public void visit(OWLObjectUnionOf ce) {
  for (OWLClassExpression e : ce.getOperands()) {
      if (!e.isAnonymous()) {
     System.out.println("VisitorAdaptor OWLClass:"+e);
         }
     }
    }
  };
classExpression.accept(visitorAdapter);
```

Comment: in OWLAPI 5, the -Adapter suffix is no longer required and OWLObjectUnionOf::operands() can be used instead.

Comment: Thank you, Ignazio.